# Link in Close banner doesn’t specify debugging details

Tags: feature-request, bug, close-reasons

Many closed questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117712/what-can-cause-entering-set-method-except-assigning-and-raising)) have a banner:

> Closed. This question needs [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently
> accepting answers.

But the linked page https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions doesn’t mention debugging details at all.

Either the link is wrong, or the page should be extended to clarify if debugging questions are allowed and, if yes, what information is required for  a question to be valid.

Comment: [Already requested](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fhelp%2Fclosed-questions%22+debugging) on MSO: [Put a direct link to the MCVE/MRE help page on the closure notice for "needs debugging details"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397048/4642212).

Comment: This belongs to MSO.